# SPARQL: selecting people by country

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to select all people born in a specific country (e.g. Portugal) from DBPedia.

I could use this query:

```
         SELECT DISTINCT ?person   
         WHERE {
            ?person dbpedia-owl:birthPlace dbpedia:Portugal.
          }
```

But the problem is that not all people have *dbpedia:Portugal* as *birthPlace*. About 30% of people have just a town name as *birthPlace*, e.g.

```
       dbpedia:Lisbon
```

I could add all Portugal cities in a FILTER clause but it's a big list.

May be it's possible to infer *Portugal* from *Lisbon* in the SPARQL query somehow?

(to not to add all Portugal cities in FILTER to get ALL persons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume all the cities in a specific country are defined as part of that country in dbpedia, you could have a query that first looks for the people that have `dbpedia:Portugal` as a country and then cities within `dbpedia:Portugal`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person
WHERE {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person.
Optional{
    ?person dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?country.
}
Optional{
    ?person dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?place.
    ?place dbpedia-owl:country ?country
}
filter(?country= dbpedia:Portugal)
}
```

The query that you have written identifies 1723 distinct URIs, and this finds 2563 URIs.

Comment: Yeah, thanks!.. Due to the DBPedia data we still miss about 1000 persons..e.g. //dbpedia.org/resource/Vera_Kolodzig.... But it's DBPEdia data issue

Comment: @gmlvsv This answer works, but it's very verbose.  It can be written in a much shorter (and possibly more efficient) fashion.  I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988780/1281433).

Comment: @Artemis, how do you get this 2563 results for this?  When I run it, changing the select line to `select (count(distinct ?person) as ?n)`, I get 2449, just like in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988780/1281433).  I think something is incorrect somewhere...  (I **do** get 1723 when running OP's query, though.)

Comment: I got it with a simple count in [Virtuoso](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+count%28%3Fperson%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson.%0D%0AOptional%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fperson+dbpedia-owl%3AbirthPlace+%3Fcountry.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AOptional%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fperson+dbpedia-owl%3AbirthPlace+%3Fplace.%0D%0A++++%3Fplace+dbpedia-owl%3Acountry+%3Fcountry%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afilter%28%3Fcountry%3D+dbpedia%3APortugal%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

Full results may be achieved by this [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/22450/sparql-selecting-people-by-country](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512002515/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/22450/sparql-selecting-people-by-country)
 - 2730 persons

```
   PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
   PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

   SELECT ?person
    WHERE
      {   
             {?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>;
              <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> ?place.
              ?place <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country> ?birthCountry.
              ?birthCountry a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country>.
              FILTER (?birthCountry = dbpedia:Portugal).
              }
          UNION
              { ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>;
              <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace> ?birthCountry.
               ?birthCountry a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country>.
              FILTER (?birthCountry = dbpedia:Portugal).
              }
          }
      GROUP BY ?person
      ORDER BY ?person
```

Answer (score 1):

[Artemis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30956890/1281433) works, but it's very verbose for what's a pretty simple query.  It can be simplified to:

```
select distinct ?person where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
          dbpedia-owl:birthPlace/dbpedia-owl:country? dbpedia:Portugal
}
```

[SPARQL results (2449)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fperson%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthPlace%2Fdbpedia-owl%3Acountry%3F%20dbpedia%3APortugal%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Why are the counts so different? What are the differences between these two queries. I couldn't check all, but I checked a few and for example you are missing (http://dbpedia.org/page/Adriano_Niz). Since there is no Country specified directly. So what is this query finding and missing in comparison to the other two provided in the answers?

Comment: My query doesn't miss Adriano_Niz.  E.g., if you add a filter to restrict my query to those whose labels include "Niz", e.g., with a query like [this one](http://pastebin.com/kkMSpmZj) you get Adriano Niz, which has [these results](http://goo.gl/9M7wkA).  My query shouldn't be missing anything...  This query finds individuals who are connected to Portugal by the path `dbpedia-owl:birthPlace/dbpedia-owl:country?`.  That question mark at the end is important;  it means "zero-or-one", so the path goes from person to Portugal by birthplace, or by birthplace/country, just like yours.

Comment: @Artemis But I'm still curious, how were you checking for missing results?  If you click the "SPARQL results" link (that I forgot to put in the first time), and search the page for "_Niz", you'll see Adriano_Niz listed quite clearly.  Our queries could certainly produce results in different orders, though.

Comment: I checked by a filter and it appeared, but when I searched the page it didn't. I guess another virtuoso glitch.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua! One strange thing - SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ?person) WHERE{   ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person ;       dbpedia-owl:birthPlace/dbpedia-owl:country? ?x }  returns 627 052  but  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ?person)  WHERE {  ?person a dbpedia-wl:Person } - 1 745 871 .  DBPedia has 2/3 Person without 'birthPlace' ?

Comment: @gmlvsv DBpedia is just information extracted from Wikipedia infoboxes.  I wouldn't be surprised if there's only partial coverage of birth places.   Many of those people may still well have birthplaces described in text, but not in an infobox.  And for many persons, that's probably just unknown information.